# Android Rooting : Facility vs Harm, Should I make Rooting in my device?

Tags: rooting

I want to make Rooting of my Android Device. I have searched over internet, I got usefulness and harmfulness.

Android Rooting : Facility vs Harm, Should I make Rooting in my device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the security disadvantages of rooting an Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9545/16575) See also: [Are there any risks to rooting a device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/164/16575), our nice [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info), and its [most frequented questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rooting?sort=frequent).

Comment: It seems you're asking for advice whether you should root your device or not. Only you can make that determination. This site deals in questions with objective answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on why you want to root. If the feature you want is an important feature for you and you are missing it then there's no reason why you shouldn't root.