# What are the problems of rooting device?

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, usb-debugging, unrooting, developer-options

I want to root my android device (Samsung Galaxy On7, 6.0 Marshmallow) to move my inbuilt apps to sd card to free up space.

I'm doing this as per this site:

http://techgage.com/article/moving_your_non-movable_android_apps_to_an_sd_card/

What are the potential problems I might face?

Will I lose data?

Is this process reversible?

Comment: See the questions at [rooting tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info). They answer your questions. If you still remain in doubt, revise your question to specifically address that. Also, this site works best on one question or post -  dont bundle multiple questions in one post

Comment: See our [rooting tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info), and especially [Are there any risks to rooting a device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/164/16575) / [What are the security disadvantages of rooting an Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9545/16575) While the process usually is reversible, it might trigger the "Knox flag" on Samsung devices – which usually is *not* reversible.